# enviar un mensaje al cliente desde el servidor con el uso de sockets en python 3.6

Tags: python

hola no entiendo porque razon mi servidor

```
#servidor
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ("Socket Created")
sock.bind((host, port))
print ("socket bind complete")
sock.listen(1)
print ("socket now listening")

while 1:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    datos = conn.recv(4096)
    print(datos.decode('UTF-8'))


    conn.send("esto es un mensaje de bienvenida".encode('UTF-8'))
```

el mensaje no llega a mi cliente

```
#cliente
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666

sock = socket.socket()

sock.connect((host, port))

while True:

  message = input("envia un mensaje")
  sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

  conn, addr = sock.accept()
  datos = conn.recv(4096)
  print (datos.decode('utf-8'))


  if message == "quit":
    break
    print("bye")
    sock.close()
```

output:

traceback (most recent call last)
file "client.py", line 16 in 
 conn, addr = sock.accept()

file "f:\python\lib\socket.py", line 205 in accept 
fd, addr = self.accept()

OSerror = [winerror 10022] se ha proporcionado un argumento no valido

Answer (score 1):

A través del socket debes enviar bytes no cadenas de texto (str). Para enviar texto simplemente lo codificas en el cliente y luego lo decodificas en el servidor usando la misma codificación (UTF-8, Latin-1, etc).

Para ello solo debes usar el método `str.encode()` en el servidor tal como haces en el cliente:

```
conn.send("esto es un mensaje de bienvenida".encode('UTF-8'))
```

Para leer los datos debes hacer el proceso contrario con los bytes que recivas tanto en servidor como cliente:

```
respuesta.decode('UTF-8')
```

El segundo error se produce en el lado del cliente porque el servidor no existe debido al error anterior.

Para poder leer los datos que llegan necesitas usar `conn.recv(buffer_size)` donde buffer_size es el tamaño del buffer, es el número de bytes que se pueden recibir cada vez. Un ejemplo de servidor para tu cliente que imprime lo que le llega sería:

```
#servidor
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ("Socket Created")
sock.bind((host, port))
print ("socket bind complete")
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept() 
    try:
        print('Conexión con {}.'.format(addr))
        while True:
            datos = conn.recv(4096)
            if datos:
                print('Recibido: {}'.format(datos.decode('UTF-8')))
            else:
                print('No más datos desde {}.'.format(addr))
                break     
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

Comment: acabo de probarlo pero no funciona

Comment: Ten en cuenta que no has definido ningun método para recibir los datos. Los datos se envian pero no los lees.

Comment: ahora deja de salirme el error, pero el mensaje de bienvenida no llega al cliente

Comment: Si llega pero no lo lees, espera un momento que edito la respuesta. No estas leyendo los datos que llegan ni en el servidor ni en el cliente.

Comment: entonces debo añadir a mi servidor y a mi cliente la linea respues.decode no es asi

Comment: Si necesitas leer los datos. He actualizado la pregunta con un servidor modificado que imprime los mensajes que le llegan desde tu cliente. Normalmente para más clientes y simultaneidad de envio y recepción necesitarás usar hilos (threading) o corrutinas (asyncio). Por otro lado, no edites la pregunta corrigiendo el código usando una respuesta, esto hace que la pregunta no tenga sentido para otros usuarios. Saludos.

Comment: disculpa pero no puedo ver la pregunta actualizada, puedes pasarme el vinculo, de todos modos no comprendo porque si le paso el metodo decode como tu lo sugeriste me sigue dando errores

Comment: Ya está, fallo mio al actualizar... :( .Para leer los datos debes usar un ciclo infinito que esté constantemente esperando. Como digo esto se suele implemntar usando hilos pero eso ya es otro tema más complejo.

Comment: tengo una duda en tu primera respuesta me sugeriste que usara el metodo decode en mi cliente y en mi servidor porque sino el mensaje de texto nunca iba aparecer en ningun lado, ahora no entiendo porque usas los corchetes y el metodo format, tampoco entendi bien porque a la varialbe datos le asignas el metodo con.recv con el numero 16

Comment: `recv()` es el método que se usa para recibir los datos, lee el buffer de entrada. El número que va como parámetro es el tamaño del buffer (el número máximo de bytes que puedes recibir cada vez). `format` es un método de `str` que sirve para formatear cadenas, en este caso simplemnte sustituye el `{}` por los datos ya decodificados. prueba: `print('Hola {} cruel.'.format('mundo'))` . Mirate la documentación del módulo [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) .

Comment: si lo de `format` te lia simplemente cambia `print('Recibido: {}'.format(datos.decode('UTF-8')))` por `print(datos.decode('UTF-8'))`. Los datos se leen con `recv`, esto retorna bytes (con `encode('UTF-8')` en el cliente pasamos una cadena unicode a bytes). Para imprimir el mensaje hacemos el proceso inverso, lo decodificamos para pasar de bytes a str. `recv` recibe bytes, `send` envia bytes `encode` pasa cadena a bytes y `decode` bytes a una cadena. Esto es así porque un socket solo maneja bytes.

Comment: si entendi bien la logica el metodo recv debe estar en mi servidor para poder leer los mensajes que llegan desde mi cliente y viceversa si quiero leer los mensajes que envio desde el servidor a mi cliente, en este caso pero te olvidaste de poner en tu codigo editado el mensaje de bienvenida, el bucle anidado no es necesario lo puedes quitar

Comment: Si eliminas el ciclo anidado SOLO lees una vez y solo imprimirás el primer mensaje el resto no los leeras. El método recv se usa igual en el cliente. Si quieres recibir el mensaje de bienvenida solo usalo igual (aquí sin el ciclo `while`) después de `sock.connect((host, port))` pero recuerda que es bloqueante. Si el servidor no envia nada se quedará esperando.

Comment: efectivamente despues del primer mensaje se cierra la conexion y obtenlo lo siguiente traceback (most recent call) | respuesta decode('utf-8') | NameError name respuesta is not defined.  respecto al mensaje de bienvenida que debo agregar a mi cliente para que reciba dicho mensaje, y si en caso quiero mensajear desde ambas partes creo que debo agregar un input a mi servidor no es cierto

Comment: acabo de modifical el codigo fuente del cliente para que pudiese ser capaz de recibir el mensaje de bienvenida mandado del servidor pero desafortunadamente me bota un nuevo error